# Dependence of variables - partial differentiation

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

When doing partial differentiation, I'm having trouble seeing if an expression depends on a variable or not. For example, consider the following expressions:

$$a = x + 2y, $$
$$b = 3x -y,$$
$$z = 3a + 4.$$

So, by blindly differentiating, I can say

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial b} = 0,$$

since $z$ has no (explicit!) dependence on $b$. However, intuitively, if $b$ changes, $x$ and $y$ may be changing, leading to a change in $a$, and as a result, a  change in $z$, implying that the partial derivative may not be $0$.

How do I reconcile these two notions?

Comment: When you have lots of variables that all depend on each other, like in thermodynamics, it's at least as important to specify the things being held constant as the things that are changing in a partial derivative. The whole point of a partial derivative is that things are held constant, after all. Unfortunately people are lazy and notation like $$\left.\frac{\partial z}{\partial b} \right|_{a,c}$$ is ugly, so people don't often use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I find this question relatable, so I am going to answer what works for me, although there may be some hand-waving...

The problem has to specify the cause-effect relation among variables. I usually do this with a sequence of transformations represented by arrows. For instance, you can say that you have a couple of *fundamental* variables $(x,y)$, which are transformed to other pair $(a,b)$ (in this case it is a linear change of basis), which in turn can be used to produce the magnitude $z$. So you have the chain:
$$z\gets (a,b) \gets (x,y)$$

If we assume that this is what is meant by your three equations, then it is true that a change in $(x,y)$ forces a change in $b$, but $z$ is only aware of this because of the change in $a$, so $\frac{\partial z}{\partial b}=0$.

However, imagine we start from the assumption that the fundamental variables are $(a,b)$ and there is the chain:
$$z \gets (x,y) \gets (a,b) $$
where the function $(x,y)=F(a,b)$ is implicit. 
Then, your third equation is a (notationally abusive) way to express:
$$z=3(x+2y)+4$$
so you can apply the chain rule to obtain:
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial b}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial b}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial b}
$$

To summarize: the relations among variables must be stated as a part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to point out what your variables are. If your variables are $a$ and $b$, and  you regard $z$ as $z(a,b)=3a+4$, then $z(a,b)$ is of course independent on $a$.

If you choose $x,y$ as variables, you should write $z=3a(x,y)+4$ to tell yourself that $a$ is the function of variables $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial b} = 0$ is only true if $\frac{\partial a}{\partial b} = 0$ which it is not given the equations that govern $a$ and $b$. Thus, you made a mistake when you concluded that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial b} = 0$.